# How can i get updated date and time of file which is present in android device?

Tags: android

How can i have updated date and time for a file which is present on sd card of android device?
How can i get the same programmatically?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think It'll help you

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("File last modified @ : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```

you can read more about `lastModified` from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29)

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan

Answer (score 1):

Just check the existence of directory..

```
public long lastModified ()
```

Returns the time when this file was last modified, measured in milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, midnight. **Returns 0 if the file does not exist.**

So just check whether your file is exist or not..

**CODE:**

For get Last modified date from file,

```
File file = new File("Your file path");
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("File last modified : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```

To set Last Modified date to a file..

```
try{

    File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/temp.txt");

    //print the original last modified date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Log.i("Original Last Modified Date : " , ""+sdf.format(file.lastModified()));

    //set this date 
    String newLastModified = "01/06/2012";

    //need convert the above date to milliseconds in long value 
    Date newDate = sdf.parse(newLastModified);
    file.setLastModified(newDate.getTime());

    //print the latest last modified date
    Log.i("Lastest Last Modified Date : ", ""+sdf.format(file.lastModified()));

    }catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I think its not possible to do with adb.